# Можно ли HTTPWebRequest ускорить подключение к HTTPS, подключается 22 секунды, потом 300 мс?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, clr

1. Если делать без потока, то HTTPS закешируется к 300 мс. Если делать в потоке, то HTTPS закешируется только к 6 секундам, вместо 300 мс.
   Объект WebClient, не лучше, и там вообще ожидание 43 секунды.
2. Предположительно у провайдеров не брежно заблокированы IP адресы (Россия), или TCP DOS атака задерживает, и HTTPS не может связаться с одним из серверов вообще, или быстро. На Windows 7 будет 22 секунды, на Windows 10 будет 4 секунды (в обеих случаях это долго) .Может на Windows 10 алгоритм другой и не дождиается конца соединение, нрачинает параллельно второе-третье.
3. Возможно ли посмотреть логи причины такой задержки, и с чем пытается долго связаться?
4. Проблема эта заметная в браузере Google Chrome, Internet Explorer лишь иногда. Там соединние 4 секунды. Больше всего Google Chrome подобную проблему появлял при ситуации с ISRG Root происшествии (даже если тот установлен), возможно одновременно один из обслуивающих серверов пропал. И тоже на Linux и Windows 10, соединение шло быстрее. В то время на всех VM с Win7 в сравнеии с VM Win10 соединение шло было как 22 секунды и 3 секунды.
5. Поможет ли на сеокетах писать новый HTTPS клиент, (должно наверняка бють видно причины)?

*) 1) VS2008

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` и `WebClient` давно устарели. Используйте современный [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0). \ Аналогично с VS - возьмите последнюю версию.

Comment: На C++/CLI никто не пишет полноценные приложения. Никто! / Этот язык предназначен для единственной цели: быть _клеем_ между нативным и управляемым кодом.